# MongoDB count value of attribute and group by month and year

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in my mongodb and i try to count every same description i have and classify to month they created.

I want to return an array that include array of objects that includes month number with sub array of description value with the count.

I want to be able to choose which description value to count and choose by what year he will show me the data
for example this is my documents:

```
    [
  {
    "username": "ron",
    "skills": [
      {
        "rank": "high",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Football"
          },
          {
            "subject": "Swim"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "rank": "low",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Baseball"
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ],
    "duration": 0,
    "date": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:05:27.127Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:05:49.985Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:05:49.985Z"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "username": "john",
    "skills": [
      {
        "rank": "low",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Football"
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ],
    "duration": 0,
    "date": ISODate("2021-07-25T12:05:53.000Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:05:59.249Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:05:59.249Z"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "username": "david",
    "skills": [
      {
        "rank": "high",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Football"
          },
          {
            "subject": "Baseball"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "rank": "low",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Swim"
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ],
    "duration": 0,
    "date": ISODate("2021-08-26T12:06:13.000Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:06:21.328Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:06:21.328Z"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "username": "david",
    "skills": [
      {
        "request": "high",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Swim"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        "request": "low",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Football"
          },
          {
            "subject": "Baseball"
          },
          
        ]
      }
    ],
    "duration": 0,
    "date": ISODate("2021-01-21T13:07:50.000Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:08:05.552Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-07-24T12:14:51.285Z"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "username": "david",
    "skills": [
      {
        "rank": "high",
        list: [
          {
            "subject": "Football"
          },
          
        ]
      },
      
    ],
    "duration": 0,
    "date": ISODate("2022-01-21T13:07:50.000Z"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2022-07-24T12:08:05.552Z"),
    "updatedAt": ISODate("2022-07-24T12:14:51.285Z"),
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

The result I expect to get if i want to get match only the description that equal to "Football" or "Baseball":

```
 {
    [ {"month_number":7,"result":[{"description":'Football',"count":2},{"description":"Baseball","count":1}]},
          {"month_number":8,"result":[{"description":'Football',"count":1}]}]
}
```

I'm new to mongodb ... so far I have been able to count how many there are of each value and display only the values I want but I do not know how to classify it into months depending on the year I choose.

I tried this:

```
db.exercises.aggregate([{$match:{ $and:[{description:{$in: ["Baseball","Football"]}}]}} ,{$group:{_id:"$description",count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

and this

```
db.exercises.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project:
        {
          _id: 0,
          year: { $year: "$date" },
          month: { $month: "$date" },
          description:"$description"
        }
    },
    {
        $match:{$and:[{description:{$in: ["Baseball","Football","Swim"]},year:2021}]}
     },
     {$group:{_id:"$description" , count:{$sum:1}}}
     
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add 1 more grouping i.e. by month.

Working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZFR2NJ06Pj3)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      year: {
        $year: "$date"
      },
      month: {
        $month: "$date"
      },
      description: "$description"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          description: {
            $in: [
              "Baseball",
              "Football",
              "Swim"
            ]
          },
          year: 2021
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        description: "$description",
        month: "$month"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        month_number: "$_id.month"
      },
      results: {
        $push: {
          description: "$_id.description",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      month_number: "$_id.month_number",
      results: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Your answer was correct, but I accidentally gave the wrong data, I updated the post with the correct data

Comment: Okk, please check now https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZFR2NJ06Pj3

Comment: There is option to include in the result count fields that do not exist. For example if  there is no data with subject of 'swim' it will count zero for given month (2,7)